# Method sort_by is deprecated - Possible solutions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, deprecation-warning

my current rails project is giving a warning of -

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: Method sort_by is deprecated and will be removed in Rails 5.1, as ActionController::Parameters no longer inherits from hash.
```

I've searched for this warning as well as potential fixes but can't find anything at all regarding it. I'm wondering if anybody here would have any suggestions, fixes or replacements for `sort_by`? If this is an easy solution I apologies as I'm still learning rails.

Thanks for taking the time to read and/or answer.

`Rails -v 5.0.7.2 | Ruby -v 2.6.4`

Comment: You can do `params.to_h` or `params.to_unsafe_h` first, though

Comment: Can you post your use case?

Comment: @Swaps The current line it's being used on is - `.sort_by{ | k,v | -v.to_i }.to_h`

Answer (score 2):

With Rails 5, ActionController::Parameters will no longer inherit from HashWithIndifferentAccess.

```
Inheriting from `HashWithIndifferentAccess` allowed users to call any
enumerable methods on `Parameters` object, resulting in a risk of losing the
`permitted?` status or even getting back a pure `Hash` object instead of
a `Parameters` object with proper sanitization.
```

[Take a look at this change](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/20868/commits/14a3bd520dd4bbf1247fd3e0071b59c02c115ce0)

If you need to convert ActionController::Parameters in a true hash then it supports `to_h` method. Also ActionController::Parameters will continue to have methods like fetch, slice, slice!, except, except!, extract!, delete etc. You can take a detailed look at them [here](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.0.2/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html).

Answer (score -1):

You can sort by anything using plain old Ruby `sort`.  Here's an example that sorts instances of `Foo` by `key` or `val`, forward and backward:

```
class Foo
  attr_reader :key, :val

  def initialize(key, val)
    @key = key
    @val = val
  end

  def to_s
    "#{key}: #{val}"
  end
end

x = Foo.new('x', 1)
y = Foo.new('y', 2)

array = [x, y]

puts array.sort { |a, b| a.key <=> b.key }
puts array.sort { |a, b| b.key <=> a.key }
puts array.sort { |a, b| a.val <=> b.val }
puts array.sort { |a, b| b.val <=> a.val }
```

Comment: `sort_by` is a form of stable sort, though .. you won't be able to get that with a simple `sort`

Comment: @Ja͢ck Neither `sort` nor `sort_by` are guaranteed to be stable, they both even note that ["The result is not guaranteed to be stable."](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by)

Comment: @muistooshort you're right ... somehow i had always associated schwartzian transform with stable sort (by decorating each item with its index) :|

Comment: btw, `sort()` wouldn't work on `ActionController::Parameters`, so i don't actually understand how this answers the question ...